# Why we can not initiate angular app on <head> tag?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs, and creating examples for the same,

i cannot initiate app in `<head>` tag, like `<head ng-app="exampleApp">` can anybody please help me for the same.

Comment: The scope of the head tag is independent of the body.  Use ng-app in the html or body elements.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `<head>` has no visible elements, so what is the purpose of an angular app there?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale yes it is really a fact that we can not initiate an angular app on <head> tag.

Comment: I know that Amit. Why in the world are you asking that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i am asking why it is not possible, it is possible on html tag, it is possible on body tag and it is possible on other html tag as well, then why it is not possible on head tag.

Comment: @AmitShah: didn't you read my comment? Because it makes no sense for head tag to be an app.

Comment: @AmitShah it should be obvious .... none of the content will get compiled

Comment: Guys, why are you confusing Amit? It is **totally** possible to run Angular app on the `<head>`. No problem here **at all**.

Comment: @dfsq: except that he can't use it, perhaps?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's another question. It will be useless app, but it is perfectly valid and working application. If OP wants to bootstrap it on the `<head>` Angular doesn't prohibit this :)

Comment: @dfsq: I admit I was too lazy to go and actually check this :)

Comment: At all the people who has commented on the question does anybody tried to bootstrap app on head tag?

Comment: Here we go: an example of the fully functional application that is bootstrapped on the `head`. Ready for production! Enjoy: http://plnkr.co/edit/qZEJugB5BCqrPt9IwVU7?p=info
Btw, +1 for fun question!

Comment: @dfsq yes it worked,

Comment: @AmitShah Yes, it works but again: you will not be able to do anything useful because all user see and interact is rendered in the `<body>`, outside of the running application.

Comment: @dfsq you are right, however i just wanted to know that is it possible or not, and that is why i asked the silly question.

Comment: It's actually not that silly, it's something many are not aware about. So it is useful in fact.

Answer (score -5):

`<head>` tag never gets rendered so you cannot initiate the app in there as you cannot have view code there either.

Comment: You can <html ng-app=""> too.

Comment: Not true. Can be on other tags also but they need to include the html angular needs to compile

Comment: _Technically_, `<head>` _is_ in `<html>`.

Comment: Its not necessary to initiate an angular app from `<body>` tag only. You can initiate in a div to which contains your whole app. Its just not a **MUST**

Comment: that's the same deal.  at the end you will have to have to inject it into html.